# Finding the Area inside a limacon and outside a circle.

Tags: calculus

Find the area of the region inside the big loop of the limacon $r= 1+2 \cos x$ (with $r>0$) and outside the circle $r= 5 \cos x$.

Comment: Please show your working so far :)

Comment: The problem is i cannot draw the figure to set up the limits of the integral. Any help?

Comment: please help me in drawing the figure, it is too urgent :( your help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Just ignore the small green loop (it's $r<0$)